# How to get results from multiple values with variables Oracle Sql?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I am using oracle forms 10g with ERP System. I have a form in which user can select multiple list of values. Like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/STwMj.jpg

I have sql query when user enter only one value then it gives result but when user enter multiple values then shows empty records

```
select * from table 
where column IN (rtrim(Replace(Replace(:variable, ')'), '('),','));
```

In form values select in this shape

```
(0210110002),(0270100005),

DataType of column (VARCHAR2)
```

Comment: Something like this maybe? http://fdtool.free.fr/articles/multiselect/multiselect.htm (I can't test as I don't have Forms.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with varying elements in IN list; you can't use those values in a variable *just like that* (as a string) - you'll have to split them into rows.

Here's an example:

```
SQL> select regexp_substr(x.rt_col, '[^,]+', 1, level) val
  2  from (select rtrim(replace(replace('&&variable', '(', ''), ')', ''), ',') rt_col
  3        from dual
  4       ) x
  5  connect by level <= regexp_count('&&variable', ',');
Enter value for variable: (0210110002),(0270100005),
old   2: from (select rtrim(replace(replace('&&variable', '(', ''), ')', ''), ',') rt_col
new   2: from (select rtrim(replace(replace('(0210110002),(0270100005),', '(', ''), ')', ''), ',') rt_col
old   5: connect by level <= regexp_count('&&variable', ',')
new   5: connect by level <= regexp_count('(0210110002),(0270100005),', ',')

VAL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0210110002
0270100005

SQL>
```

- line 2: remove parenthesis and trailing comma
- line 1 + line 5: hierarchical query which splits the remaining string (`0210110002,0270100005`) into rows

It means that your query would look like this:

```
select * from table 
where column in
  (select regexp_substr(x.rt_col, '[^,]+', 1, level) val
   from (select rtrim(replace(replace(:variable, '(', ''), ')', ''), ',') rt_col
         from dual
        ) x
   connect by level <= regexp_count(:variable, ',')
  );
```